# Excel Macro IF replace formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to replace the value in a cell so if it has 0 to hide it.

The excel formula is the following `IF(A1=0;"";A1)`.

I am trying to this automaticaly but I am having problems.

---

So far I came up with this:

```
Sub apply_Error_Control()
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Selection
        If cel.HasFormula Then

            cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, "=", "=IFF(") & "=0" & ";" & "")"

        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this link a view:
[Three ways to hide zero values](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/three-ways-to-hide-zero-values-in-an-excel-sheet/)

I'd still strongly recommend going down the cell formatting route:

```
Sub apply_Error_Control()
    Dim rngCurrent As Range

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Set rngCurrent = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        rngCurrent.NumberFormat = "0;-0;;@"
    End If
End Sub
```

But if you insist on the formula-based approach, please at least employ the method I've outlined so that you avoid running the code on (for example) an embedded chart or button and you'll immediately hit those cells with a formula - looping through to find those with a formula is tedious and slow.

Comment: It's not clear in the original question if altering the cell's formula is what they actually want.  I'd say that that was a bad idea - what happens when the predicate cells no longer give a zero value?

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me. Still I will try to make the vba code. Even if it is more complex it's awesome

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (note the `Selection.Cells` so it'll only work in the Range that you selected manually) :

```
Sub apply_Error_Control()
    Dim cel As Range, _
        RangeInForumla As String

    For Each cel In Selection.Cells
        If cel.HasFormula Then
            RangeInForumla = Replace(cel.Formula, "=", "",1,1)
            cel.Formula = "=IF(" & RangeInForumla & "=0," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "," & RangeInForumla & ")"
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Formula` property needs commas rather than semicolons.

Comment: Only first `"="` should be replaced.